# Out-line for virtual method in C#

Tags: c#

I have an example of code in C#

```
using System;
class A
{
  public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("A.F"); }
}
class B: A
{
  public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("B.F"); }
}
class C: B
{
  new public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("C.F"); }
}
class D: C
{
   public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("D.F"); }
}
class Test
{
static void Main() {
  D d = new D();
  A a = d;
  B b = d;
  C c = d;
  a.F();
  b.F();
  c.F();
  d.F();
}
}
```

This code outline

```
B.F
B.F
D.F
D.F
```

I do not understand why in case a.F();
There is B.F ?

how MS said the virtual methods is represended by type of object in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand why in case a.F(); There is B.F ?

[`MSDN #`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

> **When a virtual method is invoked, the run-time type of the object is
>   checked for an overriding member. The overriding member in the most
>   derived class is called**, which might be the original member, if no
>   derived class has overridden the member.

Bold content will explain to you why `B.F`  is printed when `A.F()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

The call to method F() from your inherited class object prints B.F for the object of type D downcasted to type A, because you override the method in class B (and class D).

Your test is an almost exact copy of the example provided in [this MSDN post on virtual methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
using System;
class A
{
   public void F() { Console.WriteLine("A.F"); }
   public virtual void G() { Console.WriteLine("A.G"); }
}
class B: A
{
   new public void F() { Console.WriteLine("B.F"); }
   public override void G() { Console.WriteLine("B.G"); }
}
class Test
{
   static void Main() {
      B b = new B();
      A a = b;
      a.F();
      b.F();
      a.G();
      b.G();
   }
}
```

> In the example, A introduces a non-virtual method F and a virtual
>   method G. The class B introduces a new non-virtual method F, thus
>   hiding the inherited F, and also overrides the inherited method G. The
>   example produces the output:
>
> A.F
>   B.F
>   B.G
>   B.G
>
> Notice that the statement
>   a.G() invokes B.G, not A.G. This is because the run-time type of the
>   instance (which is B), not the compile-time type of the instance
>   (which is A), determines the actual method implementation to invoke.
>   Because methods are allowed to hide inherited methods, it is possible
>   for a class to contain several virtual methods with the same
>   signature. This does not present an ambiguity problem, since all but
>   the most derived method are hidden. In the example

Answer (score 1):

In case of a.F() there is B.F because virtual void F in class A is override in B.

It is not override by C, because there is a new operator which does not override the virtual base method.

So if there is an instance of type D typed to A and you call F(), virtual method from the class A is called, but the latest override is taken into account. That is B.F.